# Run SQL Update Query Only Once

Tags: sql, ms-access

I was hoping someone could help with the following problem I'm having with some and SQL update Query in Microsoft Access.

I run the following code

```
UPDATE [Master Record] INNER JOIN [Family Members] ON [Master Record].[Family ID] = [Family Members].[Family ID] 
SET [Master Record].[Years Attendance] = ([Years Attendance]+1)
WHERE ((([Family Members].Attending)=True));
```

Which works except for the fact that I only want to increment the years of attendance 1 time even though multiple family members are attending. So currently when I run this if there are 4 family members attending I get an increment of 4 when I just want 1.

I need some way to be able to increment Years if Attendance by 1 even if multiple Family Members are Attending.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do this, but I would probably just use `IN` instead of the `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE [Master Record] 
SET [Years Attendance] = [Years Attendance]+1
WHERE [Family ID] IN (
    SELECT [Family ID] 
    FROM [Family Members] 
    WHERE Attending=True
)
```

Comment: Awesome this works. I'll have to figure out why it works but thanks so much!

Comment: @user2316117 -- np, glad I could help!  Basically your join is updating the same record multiple times (for each record in the Years Family Members table.  Using IN instead of the JOIN only updates the single record in the Master Record table.  Best regards.